# Change the order of product variations on the "add to cart" form

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a product type with three variations (to make this simple, let's assume it's a t-shirt store):

- Color
- Size
- Team

On the "Add to Cart" form (configured at /admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/default/edit/form-display/add_to_cart), I have **Purchased entity** set to **Product variation attributes**.

This displays three dropdown menus that let me select the values for Color, Size, and Team.

How do I change the display order of these menus (for example: change the order to Team, Color, Size)?

Drupal 8/Commerce 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Drupal 7, Drupal Commerce for Drupal 8 respects the ordering of attribute fields on the product variation form when rendering them into the Add to Cart form. To find these options, you'll need to navigate to **Administration >  Commerce > Configuration > Product variation types** and select the *Manage form display* option from the Operations dropdown for the variation type in question. Reorder the fields there, and they'll appear in the new order on the Add to Cart form.